# What is the minimum configuration (include haxm) to run Android Studio on computer smoothly?

Tags: android, installation, developer-tools

I'm interested in developing android apps. But I struggled a lot to install the android studio on my computer. I end up with an error that my windows can't find haxm.

What I need to do? My RAM is just 2GB. Is there any need to extend my RAM?

This picture shows my pc configuration details:

[image: This is my PC configuration details]

Comment: Not an answer though - Try Ubuntu :)

Comment: Please help you get a faster PC? I'm quite sure we're not going to be able to do that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio by the looks of things you're only just hitting the minimum spec

Comment: But I'm not much familiar with linux bro.. :(
I think this is the tough task to run android studio on virtual machiene
By the way thanq for immediate reply

Comment: Dont run it in a virtual machine, install it as your primary OS. Lot of things in life are done the first time bud :)

Comment: Check your BIOS to enable VT-x / Virtualization. If that doesn't work then you are stuck with testing on device (but should still be able to build app but slowly)

Comment: Really won't matter how many cores your processor has or what Ghz - it is always bottle necked by the slowest/least specced piece of hardware - in this case the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

For Android studio system 2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended , Disk Space 500 MB disk space for Android Studio, at least 1.5 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches ,Java Development Kit (JDK) 8 and OS version Microsoft Windows 10/8/7 (32- or 64-bit)

[check out this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to use at list of 4gb vram. Also, I sugest you to use a 64bit OS.
From google
System requirements

```
Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit)
```

- 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator.
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution.

  For more go [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/)